# How to hide and show my data series in javascript graph by using a checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have two series of data in my graph (red and blue one) and trying to hide them by clicking on the check box. So I want to be able to see one data series (blue or red) when i click on the checkbox1 or checkbox 2.

You can see my data series in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cJ5c/40/).

And that is the code I have used for hiding them, but I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined "

HTML:

```
     <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="messageCheckbox" value="line1" onclick="showOrHide(0);" />1
     <input type="checkbox" value="line2" checked="checked" class="messageCheckbox" onclick="showOrHide(1);" />2
```

Javascript:

```
  showOrHide = function (i) {
    var selectt = document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].value;
   if (document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].checked) {
     document.getElementsByClassName(selectt)[0].style.display = 'none';
   } else {
     document.getElementsByClassName(selectt)[0].style.display = 'block';
 }
}
```

I have also tried this code for hiding a svg element, but it hides the whole graph but I want it to hide blue or red graph!

```
  showOrHide = function (i) {
  var selectt = document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].value;
 if (document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].checked) {
      svg.style("display", "none"); // or svg.attr("opacity", 0);
   } else {
     svg.style("display", "block");
   }
```

}

Do you have any idea of what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the markup - remove the inline 'onclick' attributes:

```
<div id="option">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="messageCheckbox" value="chart1"/>1
    <input type="checkbox" value="chart2" checked="checked" class="messageCheckbox" />2
</div>
```

Then group each chart elemnents under a separate `<g>` element:

```
var chart1 = svg.append('g').classed('chart1', true);
// add the area
chart1.append("path")
    ...
// Add the line 1
chart1.append("path")
    ...
// tooltip  
var blueCircles = chart1.selectAll("dot")
```

And do the same for the second chart.
This is to make chart manipulation easier.

Finally, set the event listeners in the code:

```
d3.selectAll('.messageCheckbox').on('click', function () {
    var value = this.value,
        checked = this.checked;
    d3.select('.' + value).classed('hidden', !checked);
});
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6cJ5c/45/)

Answer (score 1):

`line1` and `line2` are the IDs of the SVG elements you want to show/hide. They are not class names. You need to select by ID instead of class.

```
showOrHide = function (i) {
   var selectt = document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].value;
   if (document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].checked) {
     document.getElementById(selectt).style.display = 'none';
   } else {
     document.getElementById(selectt).style.display = 'block';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying back, but now i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function which is related to this part: document.getElementById(selectt)(selectt)[0].style.display = 'block';

Comment: by the way, another thing is that, I have two values to be hided one is area and the other is line. ed. line1 and area 1 is realted to checkbox 1 but when i want to put values to check box there is only one value for each check box: <input type="checkbox" value="line2" checked="checked" class="messageCheckbox" onclick="showOrHide(1);" />2 how can i initiate it with two values?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my answer, which I fixed. Try again with my answer.

Comment: Thanks its working:)but since my graph consists of two parts line and area when i use your code it hided the line (curve of graph) and the area still remains. What i did is that I set two values for check box: <input type="checkbox" value="line2" value= "area2" checked="checked" class="messageCheckbox" onclick="showOrHide(1);" />2 but when I run it,it only hide the first value which is line2 according to this line:selectt = document.getElementsByClassName("messageCheckbox")[i].value; so only line is get hided which is some part of red graph,but is there any way to give two values to check box?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "hidden" boolean in your dataset. If hidden is "false" the data will not shown.

>

```html
  public lineChartData: Array<any> =  [
    {label: 'TestValue', unit: '°C', hidden: false, 
    data: [{ x: 1504280788000, y: 12 }, { x: 1504290788000, y: 14 }, { x: 1504300788000, y: 18 }, { x: 1504310788000, y: 21 }, { x: 1504320788000, y: 12 }, { x: 1504330788000, y: 15 }] },
```